# Windows 8 All folders close abruptly

Tags: windows-8

I use Windows 8, and usually run a few programs and have many folders open at the same time.  Quite a few times the screen freezes for a second, and when the screen is active again, all the folders have closed.  This can get quite frustrating especially when working in a specific folder etc.

Is this a problem with Windows? An explorer issue? My machine?  How would I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running Windows Explorer as a separate process.

Under `Folder Options` > `View`, find the "Launch folder windows in a separate process" option and enable it. This won't necessarily stop the explorer crashes, but it will spawn a new copy of `explorer.exe` for the shell and for each Windows Explorer window so that when one crashes, you don't lose all of the windows.

This doesn't explain the freezes, or why they are crashing in the first place, but might help mitigate the frustration of having all your windows close on you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder which causes the trouble. Right click on it. Go to Properties and then go to customize and in it you will find a heading as " optimize this folder for", there select as " general items" and apply. This eliminates the problem and folders work fine without any limitation or drawback.